# UFT with Browser based Application

Tags: automation, qtp, hp-uft, browser-based

We have a browser based Java application. We access the application through a browser, so after launching the browser, we work on application through that browser. Basically the application is not web based, web is just a medium to access that application.
I am trying to automate it through UFT/QTP but no luck as it is not able to identify java objects inside the browser.
Is there a way to automate such browser based applications?

Comment: Is it a Java Web Start application? If yes then you should be able to automate it using Java addin.

Comment: Application requires Delphi addin but it is opening remotely through a browser.

Comment: Your question says Java but your comment say Delphi? You should first confirm the tech behind the application

Comment: I supposed it java but came to know that it is Delphi.

Comment: If it's an embedded app (which it sounds like it is), you have to recognise the browser and then use child objects to interact with embedded apps. Too complicated to explain here but this might give you a start